# What if we have WSUS in SSM server in Azure?

Tags: azure

We have a VPN Gateway from Onprem and Azue infra, We are planning to Migrate SCM and WSUS to Azure, What IF we push patches from WSUS to On Prem Clients.

Will this effect the Azure bandwidth and monthly charges?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be charged for outbound data transfer from Azure Data Centre back to on-premises. Pricing details can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/bandwidth/)